# Is it possible to create an XOR pen like DrawFocusRect()?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

The Win32 GDI [`DrawFocusRect(HDC, const RECT*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function draws the dotted outline of a rectangle on the desired devince context. The cool thing about this function is it draws the dots using an XOR function so that when you call it a second time on the same device context and rectangle, it erases itself:

```
RECT rc = { 0, 0, 100, 100 };
DrawFocusRect(hdc, &rc); // draw rectangle
DrawFocusRect(hdc, &rc); // erase the rectangle we just drew
```

I want to achieve the same dotted line effect as `DrawFocusRect()` but I just want a line, not a whole rectangle. I tried doing this by passing a `RECT` of height 1 to `DrawFocusRect()` but this doesn't work because it XORs the "bottom line" of the rectange on top of the top line so nothing gets painted.

Can I create a plain HPEN that achieves the same effect as `DrawFocusRect()` so I can draw just a single line?

Comment: [`SetROP2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145088.aspx) with a `R2_XORPEN` drawmode should achieve the same effect, when used with the other line drawing APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IInspectable. Any idea what system color is used to draw the focus rectangle? I'd like to use the same one if possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @IInspectable commented, you want to use [`SetROP2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The other half of the battle is creating the correct pen. Here is how the whole thing shakes out:

```
HPEN create_focus_pen()
{
    LONG width(1);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT, 0, &width, 0);
    LOGBRUSH lb = { };     // initialize to zero
    lb.lbColor = 0xffffff; // white
    lb.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
    return ExtCreatePen(PS.GEOMETRIC | PS.DOT, width, &lb, 0, 0);
}

void draw_focus_line(HDC hdc, HPEN hpen, POINT from, POINT to)
{
    HPEN old_pen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
    int old_rop = SetROP2(R2_XORPEN);
    MoveToEx(hdc, from.x, from.y, nullptr);
    LineTo(hdc, to.x, to.y);
    SelectObject(hdc, old_pen);
    SetROP2(old_rop);
}
```

Comment: Just a minor remark: HDC should be passed into SetROP2 as the 1st parameter