# A pen that negates background or equivalent of DrawFocusRect

Tags: c#, graphics

C# offers `ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle()` function but it does not seem to work like the [DrawFocuRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect). The frame drawn once with `DrawFocuRect()` creates a negation of the original image, so the second draw in the same place removes the frame effect (negates it back to original colors). However, the `ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle()` offers the same frame shape but does not negate the content. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167274/is-it-possible-to-create-an-xor-pen-like-drawfocusrect) a similar example in C, but I am unable to reproduce it in C#.